# Скролл экрана, чтобы элемент находится по центру jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

В этом коде элемент находится в верху экрана.

```
$('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({
  scrollTop: $('.match').eq(i).offset().top
});
```

Как проскролить экран так, чтобы элемент находился по центру?

Comment: Подробней напишите и желательно html пример и его демонстрацию

Comment: Нужно проскроллить обратно на величину (высота окна - высота элемента)/2